# Addition of Polynomials with 2 variables

Tags: r, polynomials

Function:

```
(x^3 - 3*x^2 - 2*x + 7) + (y^2 + 2*y)
```

Output on Wolfram (which I understand):

```
x^3 - 3 x^2 - 2 x + y^2 + 2 y + 7
```

Output of the code in R: (using the `polynomial` function in package `polynom`)

```
7 - 2*x^2 + x^3
```

R code:

```
library(polynom)

p <- polynomial(c(7,-2,-3, 1))
q <- polynomial(c(0, 2, 1))
p + q
```

Entered the code as above in R.

Comment: check your x and y

Comment: Assuming you are using the `polynomial` function in package `polynom`, read the manual page (`?polynomial`). Your results are exactly what they should be based on the description on the manual page. If you want to match Wolfram Alpha, try `rev(c(7,-2,-3, 1))` and `rev(c(0, 2, 1))`.

Comment: @dcarlson - where do I see the description? Thanks much.

Comment: @dcarlson OP has 2 variables `x` and `y`. Even if you `rev` the coefficients, `polynomial` still takes them both as `x` and sum up the coefficients with same terms.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mpoly` to manipulate *multivariate* polynomials.

```r
library(mpoly)

p <- as.mpoly(c(7, -2, -3, 1), 'x')
q <- as.mpoly(c(0, 2, 1), 'y')

reorder(p + q)
# x^3  -  3 x^2  -  2 x  +  y^2  +  2 y  +  7
```

###### More functionality

https://dkahle.github.io/mpoly/

Comment: Yes. Can also use **spray** or **qspray**.